# Need help compiling Unofficial OpenGL SDK 0.4.4 for "Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming"-Tutorial

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdk, 3d

I've found this "tutorial": http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html

The tutorial depends on the Unofficial OpenGL SDK (http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_build.html).

I'm using Windows 7 and MSVC++2010.

I downloaded the newest distribution of Unofficial OpenGL SDK, unpacked it, generated VS2010-projects using premake4 and built the libaries using MSVC++2010. (As explained here: 
http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_build.html)

For testing purposes I tried to build the included Unofficial OpenGL SDK-examples. But building in MSVC++2010 already fails with this message:

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: simple_glfw, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Der Buildvorgang wurde am 25.09.2012 19:45:36 gestartet.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  "obj\Debug\simple_glfw.unsuccessfulbuild" wird erstellt, da "AlwaysCreate" angegeben wurde.
1>ClCompile:
1>  simple_glfw.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: Fehler bei der Konvertierung in COFF: Datei ist ungültig oder beschädigt.
1>
1>Fehler beim Erstellen
1>
1>Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.78
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, Fehler bei 1, 0 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

(Sorry, I've got the german MSVS-version)

The next thing I'd like to know is how to get these libaries into the "Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming"-tutorial project(s).

"Building the Tutorials": http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html

**UPDATE:** Okay Nicol Bolas was right, so I compiled the Unofficial OpenGL SDK that was shipped with the Tutorial. But now when compiling I'm getting this error:

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: Tut 01 Main, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Der Buildvorgang wurde am 25.09.2012 20:59:20 gestartet.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Aktualisieren des Timestamps von "obj\Debug\Tut 01 Main.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Alle Ausgaben sind aktuell.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  Alle Ausgaben sind aktuell.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: Fehler bei der Konvertierung in COFF: Datei ist ungültig oder beschädigt.
1>
1>Fehler beim Erstellen
1>
1>Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.16
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, Fehler bei 1, 1 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The next thing I'd like to know is how to get these libaries into the "Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming"-tutorial project(s).

You don't.

As stated on the page you linked to, "*A modified SDK distribution is bundled with these tutorials*". You weren't supposed to download the SDK; you already had it. And that was what you were supposed to build.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If I compile the Tutorials just as they are delivered I get error-messages about missing "glloadD.lib" etc. which are part of the Unofficial OpenGL SDK.

Comment: @FelixCullen: Did you build the SDK that was shipped *with* the tutorials, as stated in the instructions?

Comment: You're right. But I encountered a new problem! - Topic updatet.

Comment: @Felix: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a forum; if you have a new problem, then you have a new *question*. Which you should ask with the convenient "Ask Question" button, not by changing your current question into a completely different one.

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry but it's basically the same problem as I'd encountered before. But i'll post a new "thread".